# Passing array to __construct

Tags: php, arrays, oop, constructor

I'm having the following array :

```
$allZones = array (
    'header'    =>  array('div1', 'div2'),
    'content'   =>  array('div3', 'div4')        
);
```

I'm using it to create instances the following way:

```
foreach($allZones as $newZoneId => $newZoneSubs) {
    $newZone = new zone($newZoneId, $newZoneSubs);
}
```

The constructor for the 'zone' class looks as follows:

```
public function __construct($newZoneId, array $newZoneSubs) {
    $this->zoneId = $newZoneId;

    if(is_array($newZoneSubs)) {
        foreach($newZoneSubs as $newZoneSub) {
                $this->zoneSubs[] = new zone($newZoneSub, '');
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "1: " . $newZoneSubs;
    }
}
```

for some reason the $newZoneSubs is empty.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Shouldn't `$newZone = new zone($newZoneId, $newZoneSubs);` be `$newZone[] = new zone($newZoneId, $newZoneSubs);` and I suspect `$zoneSubs[] = new zone($newZoneSub, '');` in the constructor should be `$this->zoneSubs[] = new zone($newZoneSub, '');`

Comment: Did you try to dump `$newZoneSubs` in your constructor `die(print_r($newZoneSubs))`

Comment: Mark - that was a writer error - fixed. and for the array in $newZone - I unset it every time.

Chris - I did. it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new zone($newZoneSub, '')` - you are passing a string here but the second parameter must be an array or else you get an catchable fatal error because of the parameter hint `__construct($newZoneId, array $newZoneSubs)`

try it with

```
foreach($newZoneSubs as $newZoneSub) {
    $this->zoneSubs[] = new zone($newZoneSub, array());
}
```

e.g.

```
<?php
$allZones = array (
    'header'    =>  array('div1', 'div2'),
    'content'   =>  array('div3', 'div4')        
);
foreach($allZones as $newZoneId => $newZoneSubs) {
    $newZone = new zone($newZoneId, $newZoneSubs);
    echo $newZone, "\n";
}

class zone {
    protected $zoneId, $zoneSubs;

    public function __construct($newZoneId, array $newZoneSubs) {
    $this->zoneId = $newZoneId;
    $this->zoneSubs = array();
    foreach($newZoneSubs as $newZoneSub) {
            $this->zoneSubs[] = new zone($newZoneSub, array());
        }
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->foo(0);
    }

    protected function foo($n) {
        $rv =  str_repeat(' ', $n)
        .'zoneid='
        .$this->zoneId
        ."\n";
        foreach( $this->zoneSubs as $sub ) {
            $rv .= $sub->foo($n+1);
        }
        return $rv;
    }
}
```

prints

```
zoneid=header
 zoneid=div1
 zoneid=div2

zoneid=content
 zoneid=div3
 zoneid=div4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your constructor; if `$newZoneSubs` is optional, you can define it like so:

```
public function __construct($newZoneId, array $newZoneSubs = array()) 
{
    $this->zoneId = $newZoneId;

    foreach($newZoneSubs as $newZoneSub) {
        $this->zoneSubs[] = new zone($newZoneSub);
        //                                      ^^
        //                                   not passing the second param
    }
}
```